# Android studio application crashes on real device

Tags: java, android-studio

My app worked fine until I added a new button thats acts like a link. App work in emulator Pixel_2_API_29 with 1080x1920 resolution, but it doesn't work on my mobile HUAWEI AUM_L29.

My xml file for activity:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:background="@android:color/secondary_text_dark"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:onClick="aj"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Spotlight"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="-75dp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:background="@android:color/secondary_text_dark"
    android:text="Biography"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview25"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="470dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview22"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="280dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    android:src="@drawable/i00"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview24"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    android:src="@drawable/i00"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview23"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    android:src="@drawable/i00"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="396dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Champion counters"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview3"
    android:layout_width="396dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Champion spotlight and biography"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview21"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    android:src="@drawable/i00"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

My activity:

```
TextView mtitle;
        ImageView imageView, imageView2,imageView3,imageView4,imageView5,imageView6,
        imageView7,imageView8;
        private TabLayout tabLayout;
        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private TabItem tab1,tab2,tab3;
        public PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
        Button button;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_another);



            mtitle = findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
            imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            imageView2 = findViewById(R.id.imageview2);
            imageView3 = findViewById(R.id.imageview3);
            imageView4 = findViewById(R.id.imageview4);
            imageView5 = findViewById(R.id.imageview5);
            imageView6 = findViewById(R.id.imageview6);
            imageView7 = findViewById(R.id.imageview7);
            imageView8 = findViewById(R.id.imageview8);



            Intent intent = getIntent();


            tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
            tab1 = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
            tab2 = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.tab2);
            tab3 = (TabItem) findViewById(R.id.tab3);
            viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

            pagerAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
            viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

            tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.BaseOnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    if(tab.getPosition() == 0){
                        pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else if(tab.getPosition() == 1){
                        pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else if(tab.getPosition() == 2){
                        pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });

            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
            viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

            Exception exception = new Exception();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter( writer );
            exception.printStackTrace(printWriter);
            printWriter.flush();

            String stackTrace = writer.toString();



        }

        public void aj(View view){
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://leagueoflegends.fandom.com/wiki/Ahri"));
            startActivity(i);
        }
```

Logcat:

```
Process: com.josipjuhasz.projekt, PID: 22666
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class Button
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class Button
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable android:color/secondary_text_dark with resource ID #0x1060005
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/secondary_text_dark.xml from drawable resource ID #0x1060005
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1097)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:908)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1036)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:1005)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:980)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4746)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:878)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:172)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:147)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:71)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:67)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:110)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:783)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:874)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at com.josipjuhasz.projekt.tab3.onCreateView(tab3.java:27)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:146)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
    at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6671)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1539)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:823)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:702)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6671)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6671)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1539)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:823)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:702)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6671)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6671)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1539)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:823)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:702)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6671)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:831)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22216)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2589)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1631)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1885)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1515)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7266)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:981)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:721)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:967)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
 Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #18: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:189)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:122)
    at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:145)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1254)
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:1084)
        ... 79 more
```

Im thinking that problem is somewhere at onClick method but i don't know where. Like I said I am new to Android Studio and I become exasperated with this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a Resources$NotFoundException in your logcat. Have you checked that secondary_text_dark is in the right directory?

Comment: It's been a while since I did android but its failing to load the secondary_text_dark, is that an android standard color?